# HTTP Request Headers does not contain custom headers in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, header, httpclient

This is my angular service method.

```
public checkIn(checkInRequest: CheckInRequest): Observable<BookingRoomDetails> {
    let _headers = new HttpHeaders();
    _headers = _headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 
    let options = {      
      headers: _headers,
      withCredentials: true
    }
    const url = this._constantService.checkIn;
    return this._httpClient.post<BookingRoomDetails>(url, checkInRequest, options);
  }
```

When I console log the header I get this.
[image: Console log]

But when I open the Request header from Chrome's Network tab, I can't find the custom header.
[image: Network tab data]

Is there a way to add custom headers? I know HttpHeaders is immutable... and yet it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

import `HttpHeaders` from `@angular/common/http`. And then,

```
let header = new HttpHeaders();
header.set('Content-Type', this.contentType);
return this._httpClient.post<BookingRoomDetails>(url, checkInRequest,{headers: header, withCredentials: true});
```

Or simply,

```
return this._httpClient.post<BookingRoomDetails>(url, checkInRequest,{headers: {'Content-Type', this.contentType}, withCredentials: true});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify your headers in CORS on the side of asp.net webApi or your web server. Or web.config \ Or .htaccess

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder
        .AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .WithHeaders("YOUR-CUSTOM-HEADER"));
```

Or web.config

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="YOUR-CUSTOM-HEADER" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```